# mongoDB: Update multiple documents with an increasing value

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I've got an array of ID-Strings - each identifies a document. Now I need to update each document field (`order) with an increasing value.

This is how I'm doing it right now:

```
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  await Collection.update(
    { _id: items[i] },
    {
      $set: {
        order: i + 1,
      }
    }
  )
}
```

If there are 100 items in the array, the `update()` method would have been called 100 times.

My question is, if it is possible to do this with one mongoDB command with an increasing value?

Comment: Use updateMany, pass the items array criteria as $in and use $inc.

Comment: @Veeram But wouldn't this give every document the same `order` value or increase the exsiting value?

Comment: Do hundred updates and send them in a single batch: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/  and http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite for nodejs